# Customizing GridView in c#

Tags: c#, .net, gridview

I am new to C# programming. i have a database which contains different offers and i am able to get these offers from database.But now i want to create a custom look page for these offers(plz see image attached[image])

Suppose if there are 7 offers in database i want them on my page like the image of the offer on the top under that description. How can i do it ? i used Gridview but its giving result in table can i customize the grid view to get this look?

Answer (score 0):

You have lot other options you can use dataview, repeater or JQuery.

Try googling on above topics and try to implement the process.